# Как правильно создать и вызвать функцию JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал функцию, которая похожа на метод JQuery .toggle()
Вызываю её для параграфа, но почему-то ничего не происходит.
Обычная функция, которая закомментирована - работает.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function() {
    $("p").inOut("p");
    //inOut("p");
});
});

/*function inOut(el) {
$(el).animate({
    height: "toggle"
}, 500);
}*/

(function($) {
$.fn.inOut = function(el) {
    $(el).animate({
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500);
};
})(JQuery);
```

Comment: У вас опять опечатка: `JQuery`, а надо `jQuery`

Comment: а зачем вы вообще ваш код в эту функцию обернули? писали бы сразу `$.fn.inOut = function(el) {
    $(el).animate({
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500);
};` и все нормально было б

Comment: @Grundy, благодарю ! Как оказалось, очень просто новую функцию писать без обёртывания, как находил некоторые примеры.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($) {
 $.fn.inOut = function(el) {
    $(el).animate({
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500);
 };
})(jQuery);
```

jQuery, не Jquery. Регистр важен.

Comment: Поменял. Но функция не срабатывает (

Comment: Отладчик пишет, что })(jQuery); - is not defined

Comment: @Владимир, убедитесь что подключили jQuery на странице, кроме того вам эта часть `(jQuery);` не нужна, а не, это я со скобочками и вложенностью ошибся :)